# Getting 403 error with JWT authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am sending JWT token getting 403 error for every request with admin role for every URL with `http://localhost:9090/admin/update-stock`.

```java
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserInfoUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers( "/signin", "/signup").permitAll()
                    .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I know how to do that, the method of `hasRole` has a prefix `ROLE_`, you must ensure that the user you log in has `ROLE_ADMIN` role.

Comment: In springboot 3.0, no need to add, it was working till yesterday.

Comment: @ASIFKAIF What did you change yesterday?